# Detect mentions joined by commas in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
*"Hola @user1,@user2. ¿Que tal ayer con@user3 en #el_parque?"*
```

I want to extract the `@mentions` and analyze if user exists. If not exists i will remove the `@` tag.

how can i parse the string?

I develop on this function

```
if(!empty($Timeline)){
        $CI =&get_instance();

        $words = explode(" ", $Timeline);
        $renderTimeline = "";

        $patternu = '@([a-zA-Z09]+)';
        $patternm = '/([#]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)/';

        if(!isset($CI->usuarios_model)){$CI->load->model('usuarios_model');}
        if(!isset($CI->juegos_model)){$CI->load->model('juegos_model');}

        foreach($words as $word){
            if(preg_match($patternu,$word)){ //mencion
                $word = preg_replace($patternu, '$0', $word);
                echo $word;
                $usuario = $CI->usuarios_model->get(null,preg_replace($patternu, '\2', $word));
                if(!$usuario){$word = substr($word,1);}
            }elseif(preg_match($patternm,$word)){ //juego
                $juego = $CI->juegos_model->existJuego(null,preg_replace($patternm, '\2', $word));
                if(!$juego){$word = substr($word,1);}
            }

            $renderTimeline.=" ".$word;
        }

        return trim($renderTimeline);
    }
```

Comment: Is also con@user3 in your condition, or only @user1 and @user2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$string =  "Hola @userA,@userB. ¿Que tal ayer con@userC en #el_parque?" ;
$matches = array() ;
$pattern = "/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/" ;

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: if i like put "_" (underscore) in usernames. The regexp be like this? `$pattern = "/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/" ;`

Comment: It should be: `"/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX for this, something like `"@([a-zA-Z09]+)"` should do the trick. Later on if your user does not exist, just replace `matcher.group()` with `matcher.group(1)`. First one has the whole captured string with `@` and second one has only first group (eg.username without `@`)

Comment: how i extract the username string for verify?

Comment: By using regex string i have provided. Check folowing regex tutorial: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml to execute on client side (without posting) or validate users on server side with php. You need to get familiar with REGEX (as for abstract, and for JS or PHP)